# Python Basemap Inset Bug

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I am attempting to create two Basemaps, the second of which is inside an inset.  I can plot just fine inside the second Basemap, however fillcontinents, drawcoastlines, and drawstates are seemingly ignored at the expense of setting the inset xlim and ylim.  Oddly enough, drawmapboundary works fine.  If the xlim and ylim arguments for the inset are commented out, Basemap functions are plotted properly, however mark_inset is not in the correct location.  I followed the example by Basemap (http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/locator.html) and tried changing my map projection from lcc to cyl (as in their example).  For some reason, plotting lines and Basemap functions works correctly, which leads me to believe there is some bug associated with the map projection.  Any help would be really appreciated!

```
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().magic('reset -sf')

import matplotlib.pyplot as P
from pylab import *                ## import scientific database
close("all")                       ## close all windows
import netCDF4
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import mark_inset

# Main Basemap lat/lon boundaries
ll_lon = -131.4
ll_lat = 22.8
ur_lon = -104.1
ur_lat = 44.1

# Center point of map
ref_lat = (ll_lat + ur_lat)/2.
ref_lon = -(abs(ll_lon) + abs(ur_lon))/2.

# Create first Basemap
fig = P.figure(figsize=(20,15))
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=ll_lon,llcrnrlat=ll_lat,urcrnrlon=ur_lon,urcrnrlat=ur_lat,lon_0=ref_lon,lat_0=ref_lat,projection='lcc',resolution='h')

# Define corners for drawing inner domain
ll_x = 591679.34684650064
ul_x = 594344.51484522165
ll_y = 592839.05223913607
ul_y = 1806478.1475523338

ur_x = 1857338.6486264155
lr_x = 1807752.1722138769
ur_y = 1779256.3653244921
lr_y = 566631.12743243692

# Plot inner domain
m.plot([ll_x,ul_x],[ll_y,ul_y],linewidth=3,color='k')
m.plot([ul_x,ur_x],[ul_y,ur_y],linewidth=3,color='k')
m.plot([ur_x,lr_x],[ur_y,lr_y],linewidth=3,color='k')
m.plot([lr_x,ll_x],[lr_y,ll_y],linewidth=3,color='k')

# Customize map
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
m.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=1.5)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(20.,55.,5.),labels=[True,False,False,False],fontsize=18)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-145.,-95.,5.),labels=[False,False,False,True],fontsize=18)
m.drawstates(linewidth=1.0)
m.drawcountries(linewidth=1.0)

##################################
########## Add inset #############
##################################
# Define new axis for inset
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 5, loc=4)

# Secondary Basemap lat/lon boundaries
ll_lata = 33.374725341796875
ur_lata = 35.076236724853516
ll_lona = -121.02678680419922
ur_lona = -118.92620086669922

# Center point of map 
ref_lat = (ll_lata + ur_lata)/2.
ref_lon = -(abs(ll_lona) + abs(ur_lona))/2.

# Create second Basemap
m2 = Basemap(llcrnrlon=ll_lona,llcrnrlat=ll_lata,urcrnrlon=ur_lona,urcrnrlat=ur_lata,lon_0=ref_lon,lat_0=ref_lat,ax=axins)

# Define corners for drawing inner domain
ll_x = 1180454.8544887367
ul_x = 1181076.4843945887
ll_y = 1172180.6247499525
ul_y = 1202324.6929654693

ur_x = 1245128.2633578097
lr_x = 1244450.5310503689
ur_y = 1200944.1870238895
lr_y = 1170801.3279816376

# Plot inner domain
m2.plot([ll_x,ul_x],[ll_y,ul_y],linewidth=3,color='k')
m2.plot([ul_x,ur_x],[ul_y,ur_y],linewidth=3,color='k')
m2.plot([ur_x,lr_x],[ur_y,lr_y],linewidth=3,color='k')
m2.plot([lr_x,ll_x],[lr_y,ll_y],linewidth=3,color='k')

# Define inset parameters
mark_inset(ax,axins,loc1=1,loc2=3,lw=2,fc="none")

# Set xlim and ylim for mark_inset
ll_x = 1114487.9924679566
ul_x = 1117995.9771456306
ll_y = 1094044.0480909257
ul_y = 1283251.5520485893

ur_x = 1311637.0004658864
lr_x = 1306989.5479092139
ur_y = 1279078.0132717683
lr_y = 1089895.0682288238

axins.set_xlim((ll_x+ul_x)/2.,(lr_x+ur_x)/2.)
axins.set_ylim((ll_y+lr_y)/2.,(ul_y+ur_y)/2.)

# Customize map --> this appears to be ignored with the exception of drawmapboundary
m2.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
m2.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
m2.drawcoastlines(linewidth=1.5)
m2.drawstates(linewidth=1.0)

P.show()
```